# In Corda, Error parsing master.changelog.json when migrating to Enterprise

Tags: corda

I am migrating from Corda Open-Source to Corda Enterprise and have created the migration scripts. However, I am getting the following error:

> liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing
>   master.changelog.json at
>   liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:98)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:1183)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:1176)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration(SchemaMigration.kt:133)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration$default(SchemaMigration.kt:77)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.checkState(SchemaMigration.kt:66)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.nodeStartup(SchemaMigration.kt:49)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodeKt.configureDatabase(AbstractNode.kt:1140)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:852)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:373)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:296)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:387)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.EnterpriseNode.start(EnterpriseNode.kt:181)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:270)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:160)
>   [corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:25)
>   [corda-node-3.1.jar:?] Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException:
>   Error parsing line 1 column 62 of
>   migration/account-application.changelog-master.xml: cvc-elt.1: Cannot
>   find the declaration of element 'changeSet'. at
>   liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:322)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:282)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:91)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] ... 16 more

Here are the contents of the `account-application.changelog-master.xml` file:

```
<changeSet author="R3.Corda" id="account_application_schema">
    <addColumn tableName="account_application_states">
        <column name="member_id" type="uuid"/>
    </addColumn>
    <addColumn tableName="account_application_states">
        <column name="fund_product_id" type="uuid"/>
    </addColumn>
    <addColumn tableName="account_application_states">
        <column name="type" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>
    <addColumn tableName="account_application_states">
        <column name="fund_name" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>
    <addColumn tableName="account_application_states">
        <column name="linear_id" type="uuid"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

I have tried wrapping the contents in a `<databaseChangeLog>` tag but I am still getting a similar error. Do I need to add any extra headers or contents to the file?

Answer (score 2):

When setting up an empty database for Corda Enterprise, roles and schemas need to be setup by following the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-database.html). After which, the changelog files need to be created and added to the resources/migration folder. Tables need to be created in the changelog and indexes added such as in the example below (account-application.changelog-master.xml). Note the additional (not defined in the MappedSchema) output_index and transaction_id columns which are required otherwise a missing column error will the thrown. These are used to join custom schemas with the Corda vault_schema.

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
<changeSet author="R3.Corda" id="account_application_schema">
    <createTable tableName="account_application_states">
        <column name="member_id" type="uuid"/>
        <column name="type" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="linear_id" type="uuid"/>
        <column name="output_index" type="int"/>
        <column name="transaction_id" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
    <createIndex indexName="account_application_index_member_id" tableName="account_application_states" unique="false">
        <column name="member_id" type="uuid"/>
    </createIndex>
    <createIndex indexName="linear_id_account_application_index" tableName="account_application_states" unique="false">
        <column name="linear_id" type="uuid"/>
    </createIndex>
    <createIndex indexName="output_index_account_application_index" tableName="account_application_states" unique="false">
        <column name="output_index" type="int"/>
    </createIndex>
    <createIndex indexName="transaction_id_account_application_index" tableName="account_application_states" unique="false">
        <column name="transaction_id" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

This changelog then needs to be referenced by the MappedSchema such as in the example below:

```
override val migrationResource = "account-application.changelog-master"

@Entity
@Table(name = "account_application_states",
        indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "member_id_account_application_index", columnList = "member_id"), Index(name = "linear_id_account_application_index", columnList = "linear_id")))
class PersistentAccountApplication(
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    val memberId: UUID,

    @Column(name = "type")
    val type: String,

    @Column(name = "linear_id")
    val linearId: UUID
) : PersistentState() {
    // Default constructor required by hibernate.
    constructor(): this(UUID.randomUUID(), "", UUID.randomUUID())
}
```

Once this is setup, the Corda database migration tool is required to migrate the tables and columns (the external database needs to be configured in the node.conf file as well and it also described [here](https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-database.html)). Usage of the database migration tool is described [here](https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html). An example of the command used to migrate is below:

```
java -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.1.jar --base-directory /path/to/node --execute-migration
```

If the process completes successfully for each node, you should be able to start the node and run everything as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your changelog needs to include the standard XML schema definitions:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
```

See [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/xml_format.html) for further details.